# how to get the name of a product in prestashop?

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm trying to modify the homeslider module in prestashop so it can show the latest products .

I created this method which return an array of the last new products :

```
protected function getNewProducts($nbr){

        $newProducts = false;
        if (Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT'))
            $newProducts = Product::getNewProducts((int) $this->context->language->id, 0, $nbr);

        if (!$newProducts)
            return;
        return $newProducts;
    }
```

and I want to extract from this array of product the informations i need such as it's name, description ...etc

so I changed the installSamples method :

```
protected function installSamples()
    {
        $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i)
        {
            $slide = new HomeSlide();
            $slide->position = $i;
            $slide->active = 1;
             $product_set = $this->getNewProducts(3); // get the list of the last 3 products

            foreach ($languages as $language)
            {
            $tmp=array_values($product_set);

                $slide->title[$language['id_lang']] = $tmp[0].name; 
                $slide->description[$language['id_lang']] = '<h2>LOLILOL</h2>
                <p>Test1</p>
                <p><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Shop now !</button></p>';
                $slide->legend[$language['id_lang']] = 'sample-'.$i;
                $slide->url[$language['id_lang']] = 'http://www.prestashop.com/?utm_source=back-office&utm_medium=v16_homeslider'
                    .'&utm_campaign=back-office-'.Tools::strtoupper($this->context->language->iso_code)
                    .'&utm_content='.(defined('_PS_HOST_MODE_') ? 'ondemand' : 'download');
                $slide->image[$language['id_lang']] = 'sample-'.$i.'.jpg';
            }
            $slide->add();
        }
    }
```

I tried to change the Slide Title, but Instead of getting the name of the product, I get : ArrayName

Same thing for description, instead of getting the Description of the product, I get : ArrayDescription

Thanks !

Comment: Have you changed your `homeslider.tpl` code too?

Comment: Why do I need to change the homeslider.tpl file since I didn't change the design of the module?

Comment: Just asked, for it can be the cause of your issue. Your code seams Ok and should work. You can debug your code: write `var_dump($product_set); die;` and reset the module. You will get a blank page with your `$product_set` data to check. `Name` and `description` are multilanguage fields so they are arrays with keys of `id_lang`.

Comment: Thanks Indré, I didn't think of checking the variable with var dump, in order to get my variable I need to use $tmp[$i -1 ]['name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prestashop save text information on the basis on language id, so name and description field return as array.

You can get the name of product by passing language id in array and you will get name and description.

You will get language id by following code:
`$lang_id = $this->context->language->id;`

Answer (score 1):

To get all fields from a product use:

```
$product = new Product($id_product);

var_dump ($product->name);

/*
 Resulut is an array with available languages:
 ["name"]=>
   array(3) {
     [1]=> string(23) "PHP book"
     [2]=> string(23) "PHP Buch"
     [3]=> string(23) "PHP livre"
 }
*/
```

This provides all information for all languages.
In this case name,description,... is an array.

To get a specific language you need the language ID:

```
$langID = $this->context->language->id;

$product = new Product($id_product, false, $langID);

var_dump ($product->name);

/* 
 Now the output is a string with the product name by the current language. 
 ["name"]=> string(23) "PHP book"
*/
```